# Get tag values for a specific time and measurement in InfluxQL

Tags: influxdb, influxql, flux-influxdb

I have an Influx DB with a database `database1` containing a measurement `positions` that looks like this:

```
time                   serie        machine      position
-------------       -----------   -----------   ----------
1645494054000000000      0          uther           59       
1645494055000000000      0          lascr           58
1645494056000000000      1          lascr           46
```

`position` is my field and I have two tags `serie` and `machine`.

How can I retrieve all distinct values for the tag `serie` in a given time interval ?
Here, I would like the output to be `[0]` for input times `1645494054000000000` and `1645494055000000000` (lower and upper bound) and `[0, 1]` for input times `1645494054000000000` and `1645494056000000000`.

I have tried to use `SHOW TAG VALUES` but it can only filter on other tag values and not on time.

The only solution I have found for now is to use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT("serie") FROM (SELECT position,serie FROM positions WHERE time >= 1645494054000000000 AND time <= 1645494056000000000)
```

to get this:

```
name: positions
time distinct
---- --------
0    0
0    1
```

which is what I want, but seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I have found is in fact the one mentioned in my question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT("serie") FROM (SELECT position,serie FROM positions WHERE time >= 1645494054000000000 AND time <= 1645494056000000000)
```